# Titanium Titanium.Blob image not shoed on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, image, titanium, blob, appcelerator

I am having inconsistent behavior in Appcelerator Titanium between two tablet devices, one running Android 4.0.3 and the other running 6.0.1.

I am using Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery to grab images from the device gallery and store them in an array of Ti.Blob objects:

```
Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({

    success: function(e) {
        // check se l'elemento selezionato è un immagine'
        if (e.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
                args.post.images.push(e.media);
        }
    },

    cancel: function(e) {

    },

    error: function(e) {
        alert("An error occurred");
    }

});
```

In another controller I use each of the TiBlob image to creates a view of thumbnails and for each of them I attach an event listener on click to display the image at full size, passing the blob image to the popup controller as a parameter (image):

```
function create_thumbnail(image_blob) {

var thumb = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    width: thumb_dimension,
    height: thumb_dimension,
    image: image_blob
});

thumb.addEventListener("click", function() {
    Alloy.createController("_display_fullsize_controller", {
        image: image
    }).getView().open();
});

return thumb;
```

}

My problem is with the device running Android 6.0.1: when i click on a thumbnail image the _display_fullsize_controller opens (as a modal window) but the image is not showed (although it is showed in the thumbnail).
This works correctly on the other device running Android 4.0.3.

Which could be the problem(s)?

Comment: In your create_thumbnail() function, you're referencing a variable called "image" that isn't set anywhere.  I'm guessing that's a typo you introduced as you drafted your SO question, otherwise, it would be very hard to explain how it worked in Android 4.x.

Comment: yes sry it is typo, it is
    image: image_blob